# What does calling defaultdict(set) do?

Tags: python, collections

I saw someone use `defaultdict(set)` to solve a problem after importing it from collections, but it was in passing so I didn't get to look at the problem fully. I know if you do `defaultdict(int)` then every instance that is not already in a dictionary gets defaulted to 0. This can be useful because you don't have to use if/else statement when adding to the dictionary. However, what does passing `set` through the parameter do? And what possible purpose can it serve, does it just mean only add the value to the dictionary if its not already there?

Comment: Given that you know what `defaultdict(int)` does, it’s only a small step; every instance that’s not already in the dictionary (actually when you try to access a *key* that’s missing) gets defaulted to `set()` (an empty set) rather than `int()` (`0`, as you’ve already seen).

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for `defaultdict`? whatever you pass is used as a factory function for the default value. So `int() == 0`, and `set()` returns an empty set...

Answer (score 1):

Example from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#defaultdict-examples)

```
>>> s = [('red', 1), ('blue', 2), ('red', 3), ('blue', 4), ('red', 1), ('blue', 4)] 
>>> d = defaultdict(set) 
>>> for k, v in s:
...     d[k].add(v)
...
>>> sorted(d.items()) 
[('blue', {2, 4}), ('red', {1, 3})]
```

So if `k` doesn't exist in the `d`, it will add an empty set for this `k`

```
d[k] = set()
```

and add

```
d[k].add(v)
```